# JsonArray to Kotlin data class using Retrofit (Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY)

Tags: android, list, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using Retrofit2

```
fun create(): MyApiService {

    return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
                .create(MyApiService::class.java)
}
```

to implicitly convert the following Json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Mary",
    }
]
```

into a Kotlin data class

```
object Model {
    data class Person(val id: Int, val name: String)
}
```

However, I'm getting the `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` error when attempting to

```
@GET("/people.json")
fun getPeople() : Observable<Model.Person>
```

I've tried changing the `Model` object to extend from List (as you'd normally do in Retrofit 1 with Java) or creating a `List` field of people, but to no avail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out that I didn't have to change the data object.

The solution is to simply tell the calling method to retrieve a `List` of models instead of the model itself.

```
@GET("/people.json")
fun getPeople() : Observable<List<Model.Person>>
```

Classic example of how a difficult problem can be solved using a simple approach. Well done, `Retrofit` !